# How to change three dots button on android to other button

Tags: android

I wanna change the three dots button on Android to other button which is an "Add" button. How to do it? I have changed set the button in my drawable, but it keep prompt the three dot button.

Thanks

Comment: If you paste your code someone may be able to help you faster.

Comment: Please add some picture here what do want to achieve. Then you will get help faster. Because what you said is very difficult to understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change option menu icon in the action bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300480/how-to-change-option-menu-icon-in-the-action-bar)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Sorry i can't reply as a comment, but i'm guessing you want to change the actionbar overflow menu icon. If so you can do it in **styles.xml**.

```
 <!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
</style>

<!-- Style to replace actionbar overflow icon. set item 'android:actionOverflowButtonStyle' in AppTheme -->
<style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
</style>
```

Original post: [How to change option menu icon in the action bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26300797/940168)

Comment: But this will change the elipsis icon everywhere in the app. How can I do this only for one specific screen?

Answer (score 17):

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post a comment. Here is the best answer I found, its one line of code:

```
myToolbar.setOverflowIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.my_drawable));
```

The link for the original answer is here:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/35790470/4575772

Comment: Please don't post link only answers to other Stack Overflow questions. Instead, vote/flag to close as duplicate, or, if the question is not a duplicate, *tailor the answer to this specific question.*

Answer (score 11):

If you want to add other icon instead of 3 dots then just create menu.xml like below code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_add"
    android:title="Add"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add" />
</menu>
```

Note:
Don't use `android:showAsAction`.
Use `app:showAsAction`.

Comment: Why do you suggest app instead of android? 

This is the solution but i don't understand why.

Answer (score 7):

```
//just edit menu.xml file    
//add icon for item which will change default setting icon
//add sub menus


 ///menu.xml file


    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"
            app:showAsAction="always" >

            <menu>

                <item android:id="@+id/action_menu1"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
                    android:title="menu setting" />

                <item android:id="@+id/action_menu2"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
                    android:title="help" />

            </menu>
        </item>
```

Answer (score 4):

hope this help u, just set your xml menu like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"
        android:title="menu"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_menu1"
                android:orderInCategory="1"
                android:title="menu 1" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_menu2"
                android:orderInCategory="2"
                android:title="menu 2" />

        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: You saved me.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For those who use Kotlin:

```
toolbar.overflowIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(applicationContext,android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
```

Note: "ic_dialog_info" is an icon example.

Answer (score 0):

In toolbar you can simply type the code below to change color of three dots

```
 private fun menuItemClick() {

        binding.toolbar.overflowIcon?.setTint(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
        binding.toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            when (it.title) {
                "HELP" -> Toast.makeText(context, it.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                "FAQs" -> Toast.makeText(context, it.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            true
        }
    }
```