# Change menu icon in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mobile

I wanna change that three dot vertical icon to any other icon but I don't know how. I tried so many things.

[image]

Comment: I do not think that you are in control over that icon. Moreover, users will expect the overflow menu to use that `...` icon. Why do you think that your users want you to change it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30267758/7012517 ....u can see this..!

Answer (score 1):

To change the overflow icon you can define a style like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="OverFlow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/my_overflow_menu</item>
</style>
```

In any case, it could be not a good idea to change a standard icon, like the overflow menu.

If you would like to change the color of the icon you can use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  app:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar" />


<style name="ThemeToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

   <!-- navigation icon color -->
   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_color</item>

    <!-- color of the menu overflow icon -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```