# Android Studio: cannot add extra icon to Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am having difficulty adding an extra icon (the ic_launcher is added in the *styles.xml*; there is no *menu.xml*) to the 
*ActionBar*. I have added a dropdown which works fine (the 3 dots), but if I use the following code the "Item" text is added to
this and not the *ActionBar* (the icon appears nowhere).

```
 private void CreateMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0,0,0,"Item"); {
       mnu1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_newicon);
    }

 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {   //--- Everything in the dropdown works fine --
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);     //--- The dropdown menu --
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    ...
 }
```

I am obviously missing something simple here. Can anyone assist please?

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.yourDrawable);
    toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
```

> for other options check out following links 
>   [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267758/how-to-change-three-dots-button-on-android-to-other-button)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046903/changing-the-android-overflow-menu-icon-programmatically)

Comment: Problem solved. I had simply omitted "android:showAsAction="always" from the xml file so it now works OK. Thanks again.