# Adding a Badge on Overflow Menu icon - Android

Tags: android, badge, android-optionsmenu, overflow-menu

Is there any easy way of adding a simple badge/dot on the Overflow Menu (three-dot menu) icon on the Toolbar?

[image]

I'm trying to show the user that there is a new menu item inside. Note that I should be able to add/remove this programmatically. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer?

Comment: @NimaKhalili sadly no. please add any findings here if you have a working solution.

Comment: @Roshana Pitigala I found the solution but not exactly for the dot menu but I hope it helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73597146/how-to-add-badge-on-hamburger-navigation-menu-icon-with-badgedrawable/73597191#73597191

Answer (score 1):

First, customize the overflow button style in **styles.xml**:

```xml
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <!-- Your theme customization... -->
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionOverflowButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- Here you choose the ID of the overflow icon. -->
<item type="id" name="myActionOverflowButtonID"/>

<!-- Style to replace action bar overflow icon. -->
<style name="MyActionOverflowButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:id">@id/myActionOverflowButtonID</item>
</style>
```

(inspired by [How to change three dots button on android to other button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267758/how-to-change-three-dots-button-on-android-to-other-button), but with `android:id` instead of `android:src` in the style)

Then, add a badge:

```kotlin
// Get the button view
val view = findViewById<View>(R.id.myActionOverflowButtonID)
// Create and customize a badge, e.g:
val badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(context).apply {
    backgroundColor = getColor(R.color.primary)
    horizontalOffset = 30
    verticalOffset = 30
    number = 2
}
// Attach the badge to the button
// For this API, you need to update Material components dependency to 1.3.0 or later
BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, view)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `BadgeDrawable`:

```
val badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(context).apply {
  // configure (set background color, offsets, etc) 
}
```

and add/remove it later:

```
BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, toolbar, menuItemId)
```

or

```
BadgeUtils.detachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, toolbar, menuItemId)
```

Comment: Isn't this for a Menu Item? I need it on the Overflow Menu icon.